# Configure View as Web Page link domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have two business units, let's say ABC and DEF. I want the %%view_email_url%% to redirect to http://view.email.abc.com/? For the first BU and to http://view.email.def.com/? For the second BU.

How can i configure this domain change?

Comment: and what is the problem exactly here? If you have SAP you are good to go

Comment: I am not sure how to configure different SAP for the child BUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These domains will reflect the domain name configured in the [Sender Authentication Package](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5) applied in that Business Unit. Hence in your example, you will we required to purchase and configure two SAPs.

You need to ensure, that there an additional SAP has been purchased in the contract - as it is a paid feature. Then do reach out to support asking for it to be configured. Once the SAP is in place, you need to request SSL (also paid feature) to have your domains secured with https.

Comment: Do I need to raise a support ticket to configure different SAP for different BUs? I think by default all business units have only one SAP.

Comment: Yes, you need to contact SF Support to do that. It is not a problem at all and no, BU does not get the same SAP by default.

Comment: Ok. I understand. One last thing, in From Address Management, I already have ABC.com domain registered. If I register DEF.com domain then will the View email online link to view.email.def.com?

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla Nope. This does not apply to the SAP domain. This needs to be configured by Salesforce. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted